# Get cover art from a music file using JAudioTagger in Java

Tags: java, metadata, id3v2, id3-tag, audio

I'm using JAudioTagger to fetch the metadata from music files, getting the title, year etc is working fine but I am having a problem with getting the cover art. I have not been able to find any examples searching online, any help would be great!

Here is my current code, which the coverArt BufferedImage is showing up as null when debugging. I have checked and the mp3 file has a cover image.

```
ID3v23Tag id3v23Tag = (ID3v23Tag)tag;
    TagField coverArtField =
    id3v23Tag.getFirstField(org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23FieldKey.COVER_ART.getFieldName());
    FrameBodyAPIC body = (FrameBodyAPIC)((ID3v23Frame)coverArtField).getBody();
    byte[] imageRawData = (byte[])body.getObjectValue(DataTypes.OBJ_PICTURE_DATA);
    coverArt = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageRawData)));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my application I use

```
MP3File mp3;    
mp3.getTag().getFirstArtwork();
```

which returns the firstArtwork of the MP3 (which is in most cases the cover you are looking for). This can be cast to a BufferedImage if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone still looking for an answer can do this..

```
    AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(new File(path));
    Tag tag = f.getTag();
    if(tag.hasField("Cover Art")){
        byte[] b = tag.getFirstArtwork().getBinaryData();
    }
```

Now you have your image in binary data. you can easily use it with glide or picasso if you want..

```
    Glide.with(this).load(b).into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the easiest way is simply:

```
List<Artwork> existingArtworkList = tag.getArtworkList();
```

You don't have to perform any casting nor work at the frame body level. Is there are reason you are doing this?

Take a look at the `imageRawData` - is that being read correctly? Maybe the problem is at the imageio level. If it's a JPEG it should begin `0xFF, 0xD8` for example.